# Override XML tag content

Tags: ruby, regex, xml

I have a XML file.
Example:

```xml
<string name="example1">example1</string>
<string name="example2">example2</string>
<string name="example3" warning="true">example3</string>
<string name="example4">example4</string>
<string name="example5"warning="true">example5</string>
<string name="example6">example6</string>
```

I would like to create a script to include `<WARNING[[" "]]>` if `warning="true"`.

The purpose is have:

```xml
<string name="example1">example1</string>
<string name="example2">example2</string>
<string name="example3" warning="true"><WARNING[[example3]]></string>
<string name="example4">example4</string>
<string name="example5"warning="true"><WARNING[[example5]]></string>
<string name="example6">example6</string>
```

I created the script:

```ruby
file=File.open("./#{ARGV[0]}")
input = file.read()
...
input = input.gsub('%(?<=string \s)\s*name="(\d+)"\s+warning="true">(.+?)(?=</string>)%si', 'name="$1" warning="true"><![Warning[$2]]>')
...
f = File.new("test.xml", "w")
f.write(input)    
f.close
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried using [nokogiri](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri)?

Answer (score 1):

Your xml doesn't seem to be a single xml document, unless you only pasted part of it but something along the lines of the following should work:

```
require 'nokogiri'

output=File.open("./#{ARGV[0]}").readlines.map do |line|
  doc = Nokogiri::XML(line)
  doc.xpath("//string[@warning='true']").map{|m| m.content = "WARNING[[\"{m.text}\"]]"}
  doc.root.to_s
end.join("\n")

f = File.new("test.xml", "w") {|f| f.write(output) }
```

Slight modifications needed if you are actually passing in one xml document but they're fairly straigtforward.

Answer (score 0):

How I see it:

```
input.gsub(/(<string name=".*?" warning="true">)(.*?)(<\/string>)/, '\1<WARNING[[\2]]>\3')
```

use reference to a group as `\n` where `n` is a group number